# Почему в логах тарантула появляется сообщение "too long wal write»? И что с этим делать?

Tags: tarantool

Это один из самых частых вопросов про тарантул. Ниже даю ответ-выжимку по материалам чата https://t.me/tarantoolru

Answer (score 1):

Сообщение "too long wal write" означает, что между записями транзакций в .xlog-файл проходит много времени (конкретно — больше, чем задано в параметре [too_long_threshold](https://www.tarantool.io/ru/doc/1.10/reference/configuration/#cfg-logging-too-long-threshold)).

Типовых причин две: 1) медленный диск 2) проблемы со стороны приложения.

Чтобы понять, какая именно причина стреляет, поставьте `atop` с разрешением 1s и посмотрите, что происходило в момент "too long": если `disk util` — проблемы с диском; если `cpu util` — проблемы с приложением.

Чтобы оптимизировать работу с медленным диском, рекомендуется записывать изменения большими пачками и оборачивать запись в одну транзакцию. Тогда по завершении транзакции на диск будет производиться всего одна запись. Передавать управление в этом случае не надо (см. дальше про `fiber.yield`).

Что часто бывает не так в приложении:

- вы запускаете слишком много файберов (в таком случае до записи в WAL
  может проходить много времени из-за последовательного переключения);
- вы не передаете управление из долгоработающих процедур (full scan,
  удаление большой пачки данных и т.д.).

Отдельно про передачу управления:

- передавать управление надо явно, с помощью [fiber.yield()](https://tarantool.io/ru/doc/1.10/reference/reference_lua/fiber/);
- долгоработающие процессы не обязательно выносить в отдельный файбер;
  можно запускать их в основном процессе, делать `require('fiber')` и
  внутри цикла время от времени передавать управление (слишком часто
  тоже не надо: достаточно делать это несколько раз за время, указанное
  в `too_long_threshold`).

Также при оптимизации кода приложений имейте в виду, что 1 инстанс тарантула может утилизировать только 1 процессорное ядро, поэтому увеличение числа ядер тут не поможет — только своевременная передача управления между файберами.